# AOSP Pie bluetooth HCI not hanging: hci_initialize error

Tags: bluetooth, android-source, android-bluetooth, android-9.0-pie, hal

I have a test board for amlogic S905X chip. (p212 reference board) When I burn my ROM into it, the bluetooth constantly shows "stopping" dialog.
The logfile (tombstone) is quite long but the important part is here:

```
01-01 00:24:15.708 28953 28986 I bt_hci  : hci_initialize
01-01 00:24:15.710 28953 28970 D bt_hci  : hci_module_start_up starting async portion
01-01 00:24:15.711 28953 28986 I bt_hci  : hci_initialize: IBluetoothHci::getService() returned 0xa1b91560 (remote)
01-01 00:24:16.209 28953 28987 F         : [0101/002416.209517:FATAL:hci_layer_android.cc(78)] Check failed: status == Status::SUCCESS.
```

It seems the hardware is initialized but the the HCI can not be started. Is it related to kernel drivers or android user space and HAL modules? or even framework(?!)

How can I approach this problem to solve it?

the full tombstone log file is pasted [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/J524z6BhJc/)

Thanks

---

**EDIT** :
[logcat is pasted here.](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MrzwVhf4fp/)

Comment: Please check `logcat` for error messages from `android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0`. It seams that `openBtHci()` fails. If that is the case it should have printed an error message. What Android version are you working with and can you build it yourself?

Comment: logcat is pasted in the backtrace part of above link. I am working on Android Pie and I can build it myself. Thanks @Simpl

Comment: There should be more output. Maybe you have to increase the size of your logcat buffer with `adb logcat -G <size>`.

Comment: I posted the logcat here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MrzwVhf4fp/ @Simpl

Answer (score 0):

Your tombstone tells you that your process terminated because the assertion `CHECK(status == Status::SUCCESS)` failed in [hci_layer_android.cc:78](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/refs/heads/pie-release/hci/src/hci_layer_android.cc#78).

That problem goes back to the Bluetooth HAL calling `initializationComplete(Status::INITIALIZATION_ERROR)`.

You have to check your Bluetooth HAL implementation for how this can happen.
Checking `logcat` for messages from `android.hardware.bluetooth@1.0-impl` could help.
The reasons for a failure and the corresponding log messages from the default bluetooth HAL implementation can be found [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/interfaces/+/refs/heads/pie-release/bluetooth/1.0/default/bluetooth_hci.cc#56).